# Rails 7 Action text not working when custom JavaScript file is imported

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the latest Rails 7 and when ever i import a custom js file in to my project the action text disappears. what am i doing wrong?

Go to *config/importmap.rb* and add the following:

```
pin_all_from "app/javascript/custom", under: "custom"
```

Go to *app/javascript/application.js* file and add the following:

```
import "custom/main"
```

In *app/javascript/custom* directory add your custom js file *main.js*. Run In your terminal:

```
rails assets:precompile
```

Start your rails server.

I used the above way to add a js file to my project.

There is no changed I made to my code but as soon as I perform the above task to add a custom javascript file the actiontext/trix in my form disappear, It stops working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: precompiling assets is for production servers. in development it will cause your assets to not refresh after any changes you make. do this to undo: `bin/rails assets:clobber`. then check your browser console and see what errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out there was a problem with the custom JS file. Everything works after fixing the JavaScript file i was trying to import.